# ¿Cómo completo esta query para filtrar por fecha en Mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb

La idea es obtener el total de Importe por año y/o mes según el tipo de venta, en la captura solo se ve el tipo LIBRE pero también hay un tipo = RECETA. con lo que quisiera obtener algo así:

Consulta por tipo de venta LIBRE

```
IdFarmacia: Local1, total por año 2020 = 100, total 2021 = 130
```

ESTA FUNCIONA: PERO NO APLICA EL FILTRO AÑO

```
    db.ventas2.aggregate([
        { $match: {"TipoVenta": "Receta" } },
        { $group: { _id: { idFarmacia: "$idFarmacia"},
        "Importe":{ $sum:"$Importe"}}},
        {$sort: {Importe: -1}}
    ])
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
**ESTA ES LA QUE NO ME FUNCIONA**

```
      db.ventas2.aggregate([
            { $match: {"TipoVenta": "Receta" } },
            { $group: { _id: { idEstablecimiento: "$idEstablecimiento", 
             "Fecha": {$year:"Fecha"}},
            "Importe":{ $sum:"$Importe"}}},
            {$sort: {Importe: -1}}
        ])
```

[image: Ejemplo de los datos en la fuente]

DATOS DE EJEMPLO: He agregado algunos datos de ejemplo para que sirvan de entendimiento de la estructura de los datos y de cómo estoy generando las consultas.
Estos datos son ficticios de un dataset de farmacias.

```
**
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61bcec6b1232919d0a8b72f2"),
    "idFarmacia" : "LOCAL1",
    "IdProducto" : 339948,
    "descripcion" : "PRIM FAJA C/CINCHAS MOD.821 NEGRA T.XL",
    "Importe" : 26.95,
    "Unidades" : 1,
    "TipoVenta" : "Libre",
    "Fecha" : "05/03/2020"
},

/* 2 createdAt:17/12/2021 21:00:43*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61bcec6b1232919d0a8b72f3"),
    "idFarmacia" : "LOCAL1",
    "IdProducto" : 339948,
    "descripcion" : "PRIM FAJA C/CINCHAS MOD.821 NEGRA T.XL",
    "Importe" : 26.95,
    "Unidades" : 1,
    "TipoVenta" : "Receta",
    "Fecha" : "06/03/2020"
},

/* 3 createdAt:17/12/2021 21:00:43*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61bcec6b1232919d0a8b72f4"),
    "idFarmacia" : "LOCAL2",
    "IdProducto" : 339948,
    "descripcion" : "PRIM FAJA C/CINCHAS MOD.821 NEGRA T.XL",
    "Importe" : 26.95,
    "Unidades" : 1,
    "TipoVenta" : "Receta",
    "Fecha" : "12/02/2020"
},

/* 4 createdAt:17/12/2021 21:00:43*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61bcec6b1232919d0a8b72f5"),
    "idFarmacia" : "LOCAL3",
    "IdProducto" : 339948,
    "descripcion" : "PRIM FAJA C/CINCHAS MOD.821 NEGRA T.XL",
    "Importe" : 26.95,
    "Unidades" : 1,
    "TipoVenta" : "Receta",
    "Fecha" : "24/11/2020"
},

/* 5 createdAt:17/12/2021 21:00:43*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61bcec6b1232919d0a8b72f6"),
    "idFarmacia" : "LOCAL4",
    "IdProducto" : 339948,
    "descripcion" : "PRIM FAJA C/CINCHAS MOD.821 NEGRA T.XL",
    "Importe" : 26.95,
    "Unidades" : 1,
    "TipoVenta" : "Receta",
    "Fecha" : "22/12/2020"
},

/* 6 createdAt:17/12/2021 21:00:43*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61bcec6b1232919d0a8b72f7"),
    "idFarmacia" : "LOCAL3",
    "IdProducto" : 339948,
    "descripcion" : "PRIM FAJA C/CINCHAS MOD.821 NEGRA T.XL",
    "Importe" : 27.95,
    "Unidades" : 1,
    "TipoVenta" : "Receta",
    "Fecha" : "18/08/2021"
},

/* 7 createdAt:17/12/2021 21:00:43*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61bcec6b1232919d0a8b72f8"),
    "idFarmacia" : "LOCAL5",
    "IdProducto" : 339948,
    "descripcion" : "PRIM FAJA C/CINCHAS MOD.821 NEGRA T.XL",
    "Importe" : 27.95,
    "Unidades" : 1,
    "TipoVenta" : "Libre",
    "Fecha" : "18/01/2021"
},

/* 8 createdAt:17/12/2021 21:00:43*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61bcec6b1232919d0a8b72f9"),
    "idFarmacia" : "LOCAL5",
    "IdProducto" : 339948,
    "descripcion" : "PRIM FAJA C/CINCHAS MOD.821 NEGRA T.XL",
    "Importe" : 27.95,
    "Unidades" : 1,
    "TipoVenta" : "Libre",
    "Fecha" : "25/02/2021"
},

/* 9 createdAt:17/12/2021 21:00:43*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61bcec6b1232919d0a8b72fa"),
    "idFarmacia" : "LOCAL6",
    "IdProducto" : 339948,
    "descripcion" : "PRIM FAJA C/CINCHAS MOD.821 NEGRA T.XL",
    "Importe" : 27.95,
    "Unidades" : 1,
    "TipoVenta" : "Libre",
    "Fecha" : "20/10/2021"
},

/* 10 createdAt:17/12/2021 21:00:43*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61bcec6b1232919d0a8b72fb"),
    "idFarmacia" : "LOCAL1",
    "IdProducto" : 339948,
    "descripcion" : "PRIM FAJA C/CINCHAS MOD.821 NEGRA T.XL",
    "Importe" : 27.95,
    "Unidades" : 1,
    "TipoVenta" : "Libre",
    "Fecha" : "14/04/2021"
},

/* 11 createdAt:17/12/2021 21:00:43*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61bcec6b1232919d0a8b72fc"),
    "idFarmacia" : "LOCAL6",
    "IdProducto" : 186992,
    "descripcion" : "IRRIGADOR BUCAL FARLINE FC 288",
    "Importe" : 69.95,
    "Unidades" : 1,
    "TipoVenta" : "Libre",
    "Fecha" : "09/03/2021"
},
**
```

Answer (score 0):

ya lo he solucionado con este fragmento de codigo.

```
db.ventas2.aggregate([
{
    $group: 
    {
        _id: {year: {$year: {$dateFromString: {
            dateString: '$Fecha',
            timezone: 'Europe/London'
         }}},
             
        },  totalVenta: {$sum: '$Importe'}},
    }   
])
```

Comment: Una breve explicación de lo que hace el `pipeline` en cada `stage` para este problema sería de mucha ayuda para la comunidad, saludos